# How to encourage the callus on plant cuttings to start growing roots?

Tags: propagation, cuttings

I am propagating a variety of plants via stem cuttings. Many of my cuttings have soon started to callus over at the base and now there doesn't seem to be further progress - I have been waiting for roots to grow for several weeks. What can I do to induce root growth? Note that I have already applied rooting hormones.

**EDIT** in response to the comments:

- The cuttings are in a 1:1 mix of coco peat and perlite
- The cuttings with callus but no roots are taken from: roses, hibiscus, blueberry, rhododendron and various conifers
- I can't take pictures right now, so I'm adding the below picture (from https://cold-hardy.com/tag/callus/) which is very similar to what my cuttings look like

[image]

Comment: Could you post a few images please

Comment: What are the cuttings in? Water, gel, damp vermiculite, damp sand, soil mix, other?

Comment: A little fertilizer with potassium won't hurt. But the calluses prove the cutting is working on something. Leave them alone. That is, water lightly and wait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When taking cuttings, the mantra is: "Cool tops, misty middles and hot bottoms." This was not my invention, but carried on from years back. The point I guess is, we need positive warmth in the root zone for the chemistry to take place, humidity to keep the cutting turgid, and coolness for the most tender tissues emerging at the top. If the root zone is too cool, then the chemistry will still take place but will be much slower, placing the whole process at risk giving other events time to intervene.